# Language with $\log\log n$ space complexity?

Tags: formal-languages, space-complexity

We know that every non-regular language can be recognized with $ \Omega
 (\log\log n) $ space complexity.

I'm looking for an example of a language which is $ \Theta
 (\log\log n) $ space complexity (if such exists).

Comment: think this can be constructed via the [space hierarchy thm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem)? also does anyone have a ref on the $\Omega(\log \log n)$ thm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer below in [lecture notes](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~safra/ACT/Lecture2.ppt) of Muli Safra.

Consider the language consisting of the following strings:
$$
\begin{align*}
& 0 \$ 1 \$ \\
& 00 \$ 01 \$ 10 \$ 11 \$ \\
& 000 \$ 001 \$ 010 \$ 011 \$
  100 \$ 101 \$ 110 \$ 111 \$ \\
&\ldots
\end{align*}
$$
This language can be recognized in space $O(\log\log n)$. For each $m$ which is smaller than the width of the first block, we check that the $m$ least significant bits form a counter modulo $m$ starting at $0$ and ending at $2^m-1$. We stop when $m$ is the width of the first block.

Since this language clearly isn't regular, it requires space $\log\log n$ (see for example [these lecture notes](http://users-cs.au.dk/arnsfelt/CT08/scribenotes/lecture2.pdf) by Hansen). We conclude that the language requires space $\Theta(\log\log n)$.

Comment: I have pondered for a while but i still don't get your explanation, for me i don't see how to have anything but a log(n) counter

Comment: The input of length $n$ is composed of strings of length roughly $\log n$ separated by dollar signs, hence it suffices to count up to roughly $\log\log n$.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting language that is $\Theta({loglog(n)})$, I found it in the free google book preview of the book ["Turing Machines with Sublogarithmic Space"](https://books.google.com/books?id=vNPuNOo9BUYC&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false), Here is the language:

$C = \{a^n|F(n)\text{ is a power of 2}\}$

$F(n)=\min\{i|i\text{ does not divide n}\}$
It is $\Theta(\log\log(n))$ because of the following construction of an accepting Turing machine $M$:

On an input $w=a^n$, $M$ computes $F(n)$ in binary and check if it is power of 2.

To compute $F(n)$, $M$ writes natural numbers in Binary format one by one up to the moment it finds that the number does not divide $n$ on its tape.

To check if a number written in binary on its tape divides $n$, it suffices to use a modulo $k$ counter on the tape and go from one end of the input to the other, counting $a$ symbols.

$F(n) \le c*\log(n)$( the proof is included in the book as lemma 4.1.2(d)) thus the space needed for storing the binary representation of $F(n)$ is $O(\log \log (n))$ and it is easy to check whether a number written in Binary format is a power of two or not, so the language $C$ is space bounded by $O(\log \log (n))$.

Other interesting property of this language is that it is not a regular language and the proof using pumping lemma is also included in the book. Any language needing strictly asymptotically less space(i.e languagues that space bounded $o(\log \log n)$) are regular.